# Linux tunnel device config

Tags: linux, networking, command-line-interface

Currently, I have multiple android users connected to my server through TCP connection.

Each authorized users have an interface and an unique IP address between 10.0.0.0 … 10.255.255.255.

Whole user’s traffic as raw IPv4 data will pass to server from TCP connection then server will pass that data to a tun device then the data will forward through eth0, till now every thing is fine, Inside server I've to create a tun device for each users connected to server, So if I have 100 users the server have to create 100 tun devices.

I want to know is it possible to create a single tun device that handle a range of IP addresses ?

Comment: Wait, are you assigning those addresses to the tun interface _on the server_? They don't even belong there in the first place.

Comment: At client side for user A the ip will be 10.0.0.1 and on the server side, I use same ip then the packet can be forwarded without any modification

Comment: Right, okay, but why do you think you need something special on the server side at all?

Comment: I just wanted to  make my work on server side easy, and maybe incease performance issue

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer from ChatGPT.

Yes, it is possible to create a single tun device that handles a range of IP addresses in Linux. This can be achieved by using the tunctl command to create a tun device and then configuring it with the appropriate IP address range.

Here are the steps to create a single tun device that handles a range of IP addresses:

Install the uml-utilities package if it is not already installed.

This package contains the tunctl command that we will use to create the tun device.

sudo apt-get install uml-utilities

Use the tunctl command to create a new tun device. In this example, we will create a tun device named tun0.

```
sudo tunctl -t tun0
```

Assign an IP address to the tun device using the ifconfig command.

In this example, we will assign the IP address range of 10.0.0.0/24 to the tun device.

```
sudo ifconfig tun0 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Enable IP forwarding on the server using the sysctl command.

This will allow the server to forward traffic between the tun device and the eth0 interface.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Configure the routing table to route traffic from the tun device to the eth0 interface. In this example, we will use the route command to add a route for the 10.0.0.0/24 network.

```
sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev tun0
sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw <eth0_ip_address>
```

By following these steps, you can create a single tun device that handles multiple IP address ranges in Linux. This can be useful for managing a large number of users on a server without having to create a separate tun device for each user.

Comment: I will try it then will edit post if it did worked or not

Comment: Please let us know if it has worked.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Yes it did help me, just 2 first command is needed